# Life-cycle of an object created in do-while loop in Java

Tags: java

I have a do-while loop like this

```
do {

   SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();

} while(some condition is met);
```

I wish to know what is the life-cycle of `someObject` object and when will they become eligible for `GC collection`.

Comment: When it goes out of scope, if nothing else holds a reference to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any object becomes eligible for garbage collection when it is no longer reachable by any reference that is currently in scope.

In your example, the instance assigned to `someObject` will become eligible for GC at the end of the single loop iteration in which it was created, because you have only a single reference to it, and that reference goes out of scope at the end of the loop block.

However, this assumes that you are not passing references to your object elsewhere during the execution of the constructor and there is no other code that passes references to your object from your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the closing bracket, '}' is reached.  Then all variables between that bracket and the corresponding start bracket, '{' go out of scope and are garbage collected.

Comment: They become eligible for garbage collection, not explicitly collected (at the end of the block).

Comment: Become *eligible* for GC, assuming nothing else holds a reference to it.

Comment: @DaveNewton: it could also become eligible to GC even if something else holds a reference to it: do `a.setB(b); b.setA(a);` in the loop body, and both a and b will be eligible for GC, although they both have another object holding a reference to them.

Comment: true excuse my wording.. however, in the example he provided... There are no other references to the instance of SomeObject he created.

Comment: @Joel True, but it's important to understand the difference between being collected, and eligible for collection--it may *never* be collected.