# When will Objects added to a Collection in a loop be Garbage Collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In the following code

```
List<SomeObject> someObjectList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

do {

    SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();

    someObjectList.add(someObject);

} while(some condition is met);
```

**My Question**

1. When will someObject be grabage collected?
2. Am I leaking memory here?

Comment: The accepted answer of the question you asked yesterday contains the answer already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461132/life-cycle-of-an-object-created-in-do-while-loop-in-java

Comment: It is not the same question, the OP has added a collection outside the local scope of the loop and is placing the created objects in that collection. This is distinct from the previous question in which there was no such collection.

Comment: I know that, but the *answer* explains what would happen if the object was stored in some object external to the loop, which is exactly what the OP does in this question. I've not said that the question was a dupe. I've said that the answer already answered this second question.

Comment: I agree with you on that point.

Comment: I think I am surly wasting memory here. From `ArrayList.java` constructor `this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];` that means I am reserving memory in stack when `List<SomeObject> someObjectList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();` and I am again reserving memory `SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();` and later I am passing the reference of memory reserved by `new SomeObject()' to `someObjectList`.

Comment: There's a) no stack allocation (array is on the heap) and b) no memory waste (again, objects are on the heap and pointers in the array). Except if you call those few extra array slots waste.

Comment: @darkcrow well yeah, `SomeObjectList` will continue to hold your objects until it goes out of scope, But I'm assuming that in practice you intend to use `SomeObjectList` rather than declare it, and then do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`someObject` will not be GC'd until your loop exits. Whether this is a memory leak or not is open to interpretation. If you expect it to be freed while still iterating, then you are leaking. If not, then you're not.

Comment: I think I am surly wasting memory here. From `ArrayList.java` constructor `this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];` that means I am reserving memory in stack when `List<SomeObject> someObjectList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();` and I am again reserving memory `SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();` and later I am passing the reference of memory reserved by `new SomeObject()' to `someObjectList`. Do you think we are thinking the same?

Answer (score 4):

> When will someObject be grabage collected?

`someObject`  will be GCed when it is no longer reachable. In the simple example provided, this could happen when either of the following occur:

- `someObjectList` is no longer reachable
- `someObject` is removed from `someObjectList` (thus making it no longer reachable)

> Am I leaking memory here?

As far as I know there is nothing points to memory leak in your code.

Comment: @pst What I meant was, when it is not refrenced. Not native english speaker.

Comment: Even that is not true. A strongly-referenced object can be GCed if it's not reachable anymore.

Comment: @JBNizet That's what he said, actually. The **list item** will be eligible for GC when the **list** is no longer referenced.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The wording is not precise/accurate though, which is what JB Nizet is pointing out. The list could *still* be referenced but *not* be strongly-reachable ;-)

Comment: @pst That may be true in general, but here it's obvious that this is not the case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I am about to type the exact comment, in OP example it is far to true case. Thanks to Tim Bender, may be wording should be "no longer reachable" instead of not referenced.

Comment: I think the mincing words about referenced and reachable along with strong and weak is really going to confuse the presumed conceptual level of the OP. In this case it is probably better to keep it simple to better serve those who would be asking this type of question.

Comment: @TimBender: I agree regarding strong/weak references. But I disagree regarding reference counts/reachability. If you tell that what counts is the number of references, then object graphs (which are very often used) can't be GCed anymore, and that's not true in Java.

Comment: (And the edits by Tim Bender [are agreeable to me and] make this entire comment thread outdated at this point ^^)

Comment: I think I am surly wasting memory here. From `ArrayList.java` constructor `this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];` that means I am reserving memory in stack when `List<SomeObject> someObjectList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();` and I am again reserving memory `SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();` and later I am passing the reference of memory reserved by `new SomeObject()' to `someObjectList`.

Answer (score 0):

`someObject` is a local variable and that will never be garbage collected. This `someObject` is "something" on the stack or in a register. Local variables itselves are not java objects.

`someObject` temporarily holds a reference to an instance of `SomeObject`. And that reference is stored in the array inside the array list.

This instance of `SomeObject` will be garbage collected some time after no other object holds a reference to that instance.

Comment: I think I am surly wasting memory here. From `ArrayList.java` constructor `this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];` that means I am reserving memory in stack when `List<SomeObject> someObjectList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();` and I am again reserving memory `SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();` and later I am passing the reference of memory reserved by `new SomeObject()' to `someObjectList`.